# Debian Live Cannot Configure Wired Network

Tags: linux, networking, configuration, debian, ethernet

I booted from a debian live 64bit image with YUMI on my usb drive. It loads up fine, however I can't connect to the internet. Even when I plug in an ethernet cable the eth0 interface isn't able to work.

I've messed around with it a bunch, I enabled eth0 with ifup, and tried doing it with a static IP, I tried doing it with dhcp, I've restarted /etc/init.d/networking. I'm so incredibly confused at this point, and I'm wondering if any of you guys have experience with this.

If you want me to post any info just ask,

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information about the context. Please paste your kernel log (dmesg), the result of ifconfig eth0, the result of ethtool eth0 (if you don't have ethtool, apt-get install ethtool), and the name of you wired adapter. Did you ever set up working wired network with the same computer ? If yes, this is probably a driver (firmware) problem.

Comment: How am I supposed to post these logs without internet? I can't get them off the computer besides reading them off the screen and typing them out by hand as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes I have, I booted from linux mint and it told me that there was missing firmware. I think I may have found a way to get the logs, I'll post them if I do. However ethtool will probably be impossible to get.

Comment: If you give me your network adapater name (with lspci), I should be able to tell you the package you have to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your router. First startup should detect eth0 with dhcp.